# Launching iOS select without a <select> element in JQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a JQM app and would like to have the user choose a value from an iOS select menu (you know, the one that looks like a slot machine) when the user clicks on a

Questions:

1)  Does anyone know of a more elegant way to launch it without having the  as a hidden object and calling some kind of trigger event?

2)  If the answer is "no", does anyone know the command to call?  I think it's something like $("#select-element").trigger('click');

3)  Does Android have its own form of native spinner-type select control?  (I'm only coding for iOS and Android)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before re-inventing the "slot-machine" wheel, have a look at [Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/), a plugin that gives you iOS and Android UI date/time pickers out of the box.

You can even make a slot machine from it... :-)

Comment: Ooh, I like that.  :)  You're my best friend now!  Moving best answer to you.